# Can't find NuGet package

Tags: c#, nuget, nuget-package

I have a strange problem. I want to include Microsoft.Extensions.Logging into my dotnet core console project but it won't show up when I search for it. Any ideas why? I never had this problem. Also I'm running the latest version of VS [Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9W00K.png)

(Downloading the package from the website ans installing it works perfectly)

Comment: How about https://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.extensions.logging/ ?

Comment: But why won't it show up within Visual Studio

Comment: This is suuuuuper strange .. never had this issue

Comment: Maybe it is something temporarily. Try to change "Paketquelle" value to All, and back to nuget.org.

Did you check your nuget settings in Tools > Nuget Packet Manager > Packet Manager Settings?

Comment: try a visual studio restart. and what kind of project are you trying to run nuget on?

Comment: perhaps you are on the installed tab?

Comment: @DanielA.White according to the screen shot he is not

Comment: i checked the search result. even if there is a problem with that package, there are many more packages it must show

Comment: Try to clear nuget pacakge cache `nuget locals all -clear` then restart visual studio.

Comment: @NevilleNazerane dotnet core console app

Comment: @DanielA.White nope I'm on the right tab

Comment: @FrustratedEveryday Sadly that didn't help

Comment: creating a new dotnet core console app also results in the same problem

Comment: @StephanPillhofer, if you do not type any character in the search bar, is there any other packages to display, like `Newtonsoft.Json`?

Comment: i created a new .net core console app, ran your image through an image recog app, copy pasted the `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging` in the nuget search and i saw a bunch of results. Make sure you have the latest version of vs and restarted

Comment: Try to check that `https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json` is set as a source for `nuget.org` package source and it is available from your machine